# In MS Excel, how can I VSTACK a Sequence generated from on start and end?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have a table with start and end of date-ranges, like this

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 10 | 13 |
| 20 | 22 |

I am trying to create a list of all dates/numbers falling between the start and end (both inclusive). So, my output will be {1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,20,21,22}.

For only one start and end the formula would be

```
=SEQUENCE(B2-A2+1,,A2)
```

I thought it would be simply be a VSTACK of SEQUENCES, so I wrote this formula with ranges as an input

```
=VSTACK(SEQUENCE($B$2:$B$3-$A$2:$A$3+1,,$A$2:$A$3))
```

however it only takes first value for each sequence and generates output as {1,10,20}.

Since I really don't want to make my file an xlsm (as macros are not allowed in my org), is there some way to achieve this without VBA?

Thanks,

Ashutosh Deshpande

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(B4),FILTER(x,COUNTIFS(A2:A4,"<="&x,B2:B4,">="&x)))
```

Just in case the range does not start at 1, and the last cell does not hold your max value:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(MAX(A2:B4),,MIN(A2:B4)),FILTER(x,COUNTIFS(A2:A4,"<="&x,B2:B4,">="&x)))
```

Comment: If values are not continuous then this may be suitable `=LET(x,SEQUENCE(MAX(A2:B4),,MIN(A2:B4)),FILTER(x,COUNTIFS(A2:A4,"<="&x,B2:B4,">="&x)))`.

Comment: That's a great addition @Harun24hr

Comment: Thank you @JvdV and Harun24hr for quick response, this is extremely helpful. I did not think of filtering the ranges. Have a great day:-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a way without generating all of them, but it's a bit long:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A4&"|"&B2:B4,LAMBDA(a,c,LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(c,"|"),start,INDEX(split,1),end,INDEX(split,2),VSTACK(a,SEQUENCE(end-start+1,1,start))))),1)
```

[image]

@JvdV's suggestion of indexing through the rows is better:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,ROW(A2:A4),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(1+INDEX(B:B,y)-INDEX(A:A,y),,INDEX(A:A,y))))),1)
```

Comment: Same strategy, a bit shorter: `=DROP(REDUCE(0,ROW(A2:A4),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(1+INDEX(B:B,y)-INDEX(A:A,y),,INDEX(A:A,y))))),1)`

Comment: Yes that's good - I was just coming round to that as well.

Comment: Excellent Idea. It is really interesting and amusing to me, how you guys built these logics with the help of these functions. This is awesome :-D. Thanks a lot....